# Topology in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

If I define a topology in $\mathbb{R}$ whose base is $\{[a,b]:a,b\in \mathbb{R} , a<b \} $, clearly the open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ are $[a,b]$, single points or intervals like $[a,+\infty)$, and also is easy to chck that $(a,b)=\mathbb{R}\setminus \left((-\infty, a] \cup [b,+\infty)\right)$ is a closed set. 
My question is: what is $Int([a,b]), \; Cl([a,b]), \; Fr([a,b])$?
Obviously $Int([a,b])=[a,b]$, but $Cl([a,b])$ is the smaller closed set such that contains $[a,b]$, so it should be a set with the form $(a',b')$, with $a'<a, b'>b $?

Thanks!

Comment: With that base singletons are open sets and consequently every set will be open. So you are dealing with discrete topology.

Comment: @drhab, even if $a<b$, as opposed to $a \leq b$?

Comment: @KajHansen E.g. $[0,1]$ and $[1,2]$ are open. Then also their intersection $\{1\}$.

Comment: Fair point @drhab !  My only problem then would be with the terminology...if a set of open sets *is* a base, then it should be the case by definition that every open set in the topology can be written as unions of opens in the base.  At any rate, I think I understand what the OP is trying to say.

Comment: @KajHansen Yes, you have a point there. Actually the proposed base is no [base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)). One of the characteristics of a base is that finite intersections of its elements can be written as unions of base elements.

Answer (score 3):

Since singletons are open sets under this topology, every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is open, i.e. we actually have the discrete topology (since every set is a union of singletons, and topologies are closed under unions). Therefore, for any $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, we have $\mathrm{Int}(X) = \mathrm{Cl}(X) = X$, and $\mathrm{Fr}(X) = \varnothing$.

EDIT- As pointed out by drhab, OP's set is not a base for any topology, and so this answer applies if we consider it as a subbase.

Comment: "this topology" actually does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

My comment to your question was too hasty.

Actually **no** topology on $\mathbb R$ having $\mathcal B:=\{[a,b]\in\wp(\mathbb R):a<b\}$ as base **exists**.

If this was not true and $\tau$ would be the topology having $\mathcal B$ as base then $\tau$ would contain all singletons, since they can be written as intersection of closed intervals. However, the singletons cannot be written as a union of elements of $\mathcal B$ so $\mathcal B$ does not serve as base.

In general if $X$ is a set then a collection $\mathcal V\subseteq\wp(X)$ will serve as the [base of a topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)) if:

- for every pair $V,W\in\mathcal V$ the intersection $V\cap W$ can be written as a union of elements of $\mathcal V$.
- $X=\bigcup\mathcal V$, i.e $X$ is covered by $\mathcal V$.

In that case the topology consists of all sets that can be written as union of elements of $\mathcal V$

If here you are after a topology that contains $\mathcal B$ then you will end up with the discrete topology (following directly from the fact that singletons are open in it), and $\mathcal B$ does not serve as **base**, but as **subbase**. For that see the answer of florence.